# Compilator (GCC) cross-compilation (to windows) on linux - how can I build it in non-source directory?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm trying to install cross-compiler using that [tutorial](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Install_The_Mingw_Cross-Compiler) .
I got stuck cross-compiling [GCC version 4.9.1](ftp://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/sourceware.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-4.9.1/) using my native linux-GCC compiler. I occured an [error](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/applications/172812-solved-gcc-make-error-missing-libgcc-mvars.html) during the installation and the solution is to build it in non-source directory. However, I have no idea how can I do it. I've read the documentation. However, it hasn't helped me.
I just want to install C++ and C version.

Comment: Are you trying to build windows executables on Linux?

Comment: Yes. I want to cross-compile my wxWidgets programs on linux to windows. I follow that tutorial: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Cross-Compiling_Under_Linux .And I want to install MinGW cross-compiler by hand because on lubuntu 14.04 cross-compiler in repository doesn't support C++11 standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't done this for ages but I think it means create a new empty directory and run configure from there, i.e. rather than

```
cd /usr/src/crosscompiler
./configure ...
```

do

```
mkdir /usr/src/crosscompiler-build
cd /usr/src/crosscompiler-build
/usr/src/crosscompiler/configure ...
```

which will then set up the build environment and make files in that new directory to use the source tree from the old directory. (If that doesn't work, you could try putting the empty directory inside the source tree, e.g. /usr/src/crosscompiler/build)

That all said, I thought a separate build directory has been the only way to build GCC for 10+ years, so I'm surprised the tutorial says anything different. You can build binutils into a separate path too, and there are ways of combining the GCC and binutils sources so that they can be built in one go too.

Comment: Great answer! You've helped me so much!
I haven't thought that I can build in other directory in such an easy way. Now everything works ok. However, I have to link libs statically using -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  .